# Neo4j query with condition on concatenated string is very slow

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have Person nodes with basic string fields such (firstName,lastName, fatherName,motherName) and trying to link nodes based on those fields.

A simple query where I compare motherName to concatenation of first name and last name such as

```
match(p1:Person) match (p2:Person) where p1.motherName=p2.firstName+' '+ p2.lastName return p1,p2  limit 500
```

takes around 1 hour , (removing ' ' from the concatenation does not make a difference ). Using match(p1:Person),(p2:Person) also makes no difference

While if comparing exact fields such as

```
 match(p1:Person) match (p2:Person) where p1.motherName=p2.firstName return p1,p2  limit 500
```

only takes a few seconds.

I have noticed something peculiar regarding transaction memory which is that in the first query the **estimatedUsedHeapMemory** is always **2097152** and **currentQueryAllocatedBytes** is **64**,

but I see the database is consuming around **7.5 GB** of memory.

When running the 2nd query, the numbers for memory used for the heap and query are much bigger. Could it be that something special is causing the query to not be able to use as much memory as it needs as thus is slow?

I had successfully ran a query on all the data to link persons and fathers, that matches on exact fields, which took 2.5 hours. while the query for the mothers which needs to compare concatenated strings was still running after 9 hours with no result.

Query for father linking, which was successful.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"match (p1:Person) match(p2:Person) where p1.fatherName=p2.firstName and p1.lastName=p2.lastName and p1.dateOfBirth>p2.dateOfBirth return p1,p2", 
"MERGE (p1)-[:CHILD_OF {parentRelationship:'FATHER'}]->(p2)",  
{batchSize:5000})
```

I have 4 million nodes, my db size is 3.14 gb , these are my memory settings

- NEO4J_server_memory_heap_max__size=5G
- NEO4J_server_memory_heap_initial__size=5G
- NEO4J_server_memory_pagecache_size=7G

I have tried to first the fast query on the data, so that it could load the data in the memory.
I tried concatenating without '', nothing helps.
I previously had a range index on firstname, which caused the father's query to also be super slow and also have the limit on used memory, I had to drop it in order to get that query to work

Comment: I ended up creating a new field which is the result of the concatenation and changed the query to do the comparison of motherName on that new field.
Discussion on  [Neo4j Forum](https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/comparison-on-concatenated-string-extremely-slow/m-p/63599#M37498)

Answer (score -1):

Below are my suggestions:

1. Index the field dateOfBirth on Person node.
2. String comparison always slows down when there is a large set of data. To compare strings directly try using apoc.util.md5() https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/overview/apoc.util/apoc.util.md5/
   This produces the hash value of the string passed which makes the comparison fast. So your query will be

`CALL apoc.periodic.iterate( "match (p1:Person) match(p2:Person) where apoc.util.md5([p1.fatherName]) = apoc.util.md5([p2.firstName]) and apoc.util.md5([p1.lastName]) = apoc.util.md5([p2.lastName]) and p1.dateOfBirth > p2.dateOfBirth return p1,p2",  "MERGE (p1)-[:CHILD_OF {parentRelationship:'FATHER'}]->(p2)",   {batchSize:5000})`

Hope this helps!